# Olloclip Macro 21x lens for iPhone able to shoot objects far away?

Tags: lens, macro, zoom, iphone

Can Olloclip Macro 21x lens for iPhone be used for shooting objects far away? (note: amateur in photography and lenses seeking help from experts)

Comment: You want a *telephoto* lens.

Answer (score 3):

No, the Olloclip Macro 21x lens allows you to get very close to your subject to make small things look bigger. It will not let you shoot objects far away.

It will magnify things sort of like a microscope, not a telescope.